# How to react to spam in edits?

Tags: support

So, this just happened:

[image: Happening]

I've never seen a "spam edit" before, so I want to know what actions to take in such a case? I've just rejected the edit with the "spam" selection set.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is the answer you are looking for, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234932/if-i-see-a-spam-vandalism-suggested-edit-should-i-do-anything-extra-about-it

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh Yep, exactly :D Is this flagable as a duplicate?

Comment: @OddDeer Apparently no, I tried to do it for fun (never seen a cross-site duplicate) and it appears there is no such thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Charlie Brumbaugh](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8794/charlie-brumbaugh) linked the relevant meta.SE question [If I see a spam vandalism suggested edit, should I do anything extra about it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234932/if-i-see-a-spam-vandalism-suggested-edit-should-i-do-anything-extra-about-it) in the comments. For reference I cite the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234954/295537) by [Grace Note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/146126/grace-note):

> The best thing you should do when reviewing these is to mark them as
>   rejected with the "This edit introduces spam, defaces the post in some
>   way, or is otherwise inappropriate." reason, as you did. We track data
>   on edits rejected with that reason in the same way we monitor for
>   posts that are deleted via spam flags, which is used to help protect
>   against future spam. You don't need to do more than that, setting that
>   rejection reason is your task and we'll be handling the rest from
>   there. ♪
>
> That said if you do identify particular strings of a specific sort of
>   spam, raising a meta as you are now or reporting via the Contact Us
>   form so that we may consider additional measures, that never hurts to
>   do as well. But for general spam handling, just using the right
>   rejection reason will be fine.

Comment: I was going to do this, so the answer was in the question rather than just a link to SE meta. Thanks for beating me to it!